# Are all exceptions supressed in Rail integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, internationalization, integration

I've recently spotted a missing I18n translation in a Rails project, but I have enabled exceptions in the test environment so I would have expected to have found it during testing.  It seems that integration tests happily ignore exceptions, or perhaps I18n has chosen not to throw one.

Is this just the way Rails works or is there some magic flag that I've somehow enabled?  I can create a unit test to repro the issue but since I already have an integration test that hits exactly the right code, it would be nice if I could use that.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using? `raise_on_missing_translations` works on 4.1.0 and higher. See here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/foolproof-i18n-setup-in-rails

Comment: 4.2.2.  I suspect something is screwey somewhere because I've now written a controller test and it doesn't catch the exception either.  But it's 100% reproducible 'live', with my flash text saying:


    `translation missing: en.xxxxsignup_welcome`


And it's genuine, I know exactly what the fix is but I want my tests to work first.

Comment: Umm, it's not because I'm putting the text into 'flash' by any chance?  According to the I18n docs, the text should be wrapped in `span class="translation_missing">` but looking at the source for my page, I don't see this.  Has using 'flash' (or bootstrap?) stripped this formatting?

I do see exceptions when translations are missing elsewhere on the page.

Comment: That setting only catches missing translations in views - if you have missing translations in controller or models, they will not be caught.

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing.  Most of my controller tests correctly throw an exception; it's just this one test that is using 'Flash' that doesn't.  Similarly I have an integration test that is also not catching the bug.
FYI, to work around this I've used 'alias_method' to allow me redefine 'get' in ActionController::TestCase to do the original 'get' and then look for the explicit 'Missing translation:' text in any successful responses.  Done the same for other functions for ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest too.  
It's both fun and nasty but is in 'test only' classes so should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what the comments about translations in **views** were telling me is that there is an `ActionView::Helper::Translation` class that extends `I18n.t()` so that it throws the exceptions I was expecting.  However my test includes testing some code in a **controller** that sets some 'Flash' by calling `t()`.  In the context of a **controller**, this is the basic `t()` so I don't get an exception when things go wrong.
So either I can live with this, do naughty extending of the `get()` and similar functions as I've indicated or I could possibly extend the `ApplicationController` class to add this function but it seems that I might be able to create an `ActionController::Helper::Translation` mirroring the View helper.

Comment: FYI, I've now given up on this method of spotting missing translations and am using the `i18n-tasks` gem.  This has command line tools and can be used to create an 'I18n integration test' that spots both missing and unused translations.  And if you use YAML aliases, you can configure `i18n-tasks` to ignore these in your test.